# Jms deserialize xml setter not working but it works fine with json

Tags: xml, jms, deserialization

Please help me with next issue:

```
$data = $this->_jmsSerializer->deserialize('<INF_NEW OKPO="null"></INF_NEW>', 'Entity\InfNew', 'xml');
```

Annotations:

```
/**
     * @JMS\Accessor(getter="getOKPO",setter="setOKPO")
     * @JMS\Type("string")
     * @JMS\Groups({"INF_NEW"})
     * @JMS\SerializedName("OKPO")
     * @JMS\XmlAttribute
     */
    private $_OKPO;
```

Getter and Setter:

```
public function setOKPO($OKPO)
    {
        $this->_OKPO = 'test';
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getOKPO()
    {
        return 'test';
    }
```

Result of dumping $data:
 -_OKPO: "null"

But:

```
$data = $this->_jmsSerializer->deserialize('{"OKPO":"null"}', 'Entity\InfNew', 'json');
```

Result of dumping $data:
 -_OKPO: "test"